# Query get api with array

Tags: laravel

I need to fetch information and bring it into an array, but errors are occurring.

Below the code of the class that makes the get query

```
public function getByLoja(string $uuid): array
{
    $query = HorarioLoja::all();

    $query = $query->where('loja', function ($loja) use ($uuid) {
        $loja->where('uuid', $uuid);
    });

    $horariosDaLoja = $query->get();

    $saida = [];
    foreach ($horariosDaLoja as $horario) {
        $saida[] = $this->horarioLojaTransformador->paraModelo($horario);
    }

    return $saida;
}
```

Below the model code

```
class HorarioLoja extends Model
{
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
    protected $table = 'horario_lojas';

    public function loja()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Loja::class, 'loja_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Error:

> Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in /var/www/html/code/app/Persistencia/Laravel/Repositorios/HorariosLojasRepositorioLaravel.php on line 32 and at least 1 expected {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in /var/www/html/code/app/Persistencia/Laravel/Repositorios/HorariosLojasRepositorioLaravel.php on line 32 and at least 1 expected at /var/www/html/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:874)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `all()` with an Eloquent model you're actually executing the query.

You can simply remove the call to `all()` and have:

```
public function getByLoja(string $uuid): array
{
    $horariosDaLoja = HorarioLoja::whereHas('loja', function ($loja) use ($uuid) {
        $loja->where('uuid', $uuid);
    })->get();

    $saida = [];
    foreach ($horariosDaLoja as $horario) {
        $saida[] = $this->horarioLojaTransformador->paraModelo($horario);
    }

    return $saida;
}
```

---

Since using `get()` with Eloquent will return a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections) you could even do something like:

```
public function getByLoja(string $uuid): array
{
    return HorarioLoja::whereHas('loja', function ($loja) use ($uuid) {
            $loja->where('uuid', $uuid);
        })
        ->get()
        ->map(function ($horario) {
            return $this->horarioLojaTransformador->paraModelo($horario);
        })
        ->toArray();
}
```

Comment: column error is occurring, I believe the correct would not be where but wherehas.

Comment: @RichardNicson Sorry, I didn't even notice that, I'd just copied and pasted the code from your question...my bad. Have you tried the code with `whereHas` and did it work?

Comment: @RichardNicson What's the error you're getting now?

Comment: "mensagem": "Undefined variable: horario",

Comment: @RichardNicson If you're going off the second example, I've just updated it. I'd forgotten to replace `$item` with `$horario`.

Answer (score 0):

method get for collection need a value, check doc :[Collection-Get](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-get)

so you don't need this ->

```
$horariosDaLoja = $query->get();
```

becouse here

```
       $query = HorarioLoja::all();
       $query = $query->where('loja', function($loja) use ($uuid) {
            $loja->where('uuid', $uuid);
        });
```

you have your records in $query
and you can use ->toArray method for collection, check [toArray](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-toarray)

```
           $query = $query->where('loja', function($loja) use ($uuid) {
            $loja->where('uuid', $uuid);
        })->toArray();
```